# Matplotlib imshow() doesn't display numpy.ones array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

So this seems like a bug, but it could be intended behavior.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot    as pyplot
import numpy                as np

array = np.ones([10, 10])
# array[0, 0] = 0

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.imshow(array, cmap=pyplot.cm.binary)
pyplot.show()
```

The result is a white image and not a black one as expected:

[image: All pixels are white]

What's weird about this behavior is that uncommenting one line an changing one pixel seemingly "fixes" the problem:

[image: All but one pixels are black]

Closest explanation that I found [online](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8467/), was:

> [...] The issue is that when initialising the image with a uniform array, the minimum and maximum of the colormap are identical. As we are only changing the data, not the colormap, all images are shown as being of uniform colour.

With that explanation in mind, how do I fix this behavior?

Comment: I tested your code. The result seems OK if I use grayscale colormap instead: `ax.imshow(array, cmap=pyplot.cm.gray)`

Comment: It doesn't really solve it. Using pyplot.cm.gray will result in a same bug if you replace numpy.ones with numpy.zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) of `imshow` are left unspecified, `imshow` sets them to be

```
vmin = array.min()   # in this case, vmin=1
vmax = array.max()   # in this case, vmax=1
```

It then [*normalizes*](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html) the `array` values to fall between 0 and 1, using `matplotlib.colors.Normalize` by default.

```
In [99]: norm = mcolors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=1)

In [100]: norm(1)
Out[100]: 0.0
```

Thus each point in `array` is mapped to the color associated with 0.0:

```
In [101]: plt.cm.binary(0)
Out[101]: (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)  # white
```

---

Usually `array` will contain a variety of values and matplotlib's normalization will just "do the right thing" for you automatically. However, in these corner cases where `array` consists of only one value, you may need to set `vmin` and `vmax` explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot    as pyplot
import numpy                as np

array = np.ones([10, 10])
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.imshow(array, cmap=pyplot.cm.binary, vmin=0, vmax=1)
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

---

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but you have answered this very question already 5 years ago. So see this as motivation in the strive to have the good answers all in one place. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can sidestep this problem by using explicit colors instead of color mapping:

```
array = np.zeros((10, 10, 3), 'u1')
#array[0, 0, :] = 255

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.imshow(array)
pyplot.show()
```

This way, zero means black and (255,255,255) means white (in RGB).